# How to write a book using IEEEtran template?

Tags: ieeetran, books, ieee-style

I am compiling a longish project report which should go in the `IEEEtran` format. Since the document runs into 100+ pages, we felt it is better to write it like a thesis than a research paper. Basically, we want to break it down into several chapters.

However, as per my understanding, the `\chapter` environment is available only in document type `report` (and perhaps `scrreprt`). `IEEEtran` format, on the other hand, is meant for research articles which are broken down in several 'sections', but not 'chapters'. I am unable to make chapters work in it.

How do I acommplish the needful?

Comment: Why does this require to go in the `IEEEtran` format? It is a matter of appearance just because you like it and you will publish it only as a PDF or it is required by a publisher? I ask this because the answer changes.

Comment: @Astrinus It is a report for a funded project. The format is prescribed by our funding agency.

Comment: What should you provide? The PDF or the LaTeX source?

Comment: @Astrinus Just the PDF

Comment: Ok, then you can borrow from `report` or `book` document classes the macros `\chapter` and `\l@chapter` and all their dipendencies.

Comment: @Astrinus ehh... I am pretty novice to make any sense of that. You mind posting that as an answer, and giving more details ?

Answer (score 2):

Try to insert this in the preamble (**not tested**, so maybe it will mess all up):

```
\makeatletter

\newcounter{chapter}

\ifCLASSOPTIONcompsoc
\def\thechapter{\arabic{chapter}}
  \ifCLASSOPTIONconference% compsoc conference
    \def\thechapterdis{\thechapter.}
  \else% compsoc not conferencs
    \def\thechapterdis{\thechapter.}
  \fi
\else
\def\thechapter{\Roman{chapter}}
\def\thechapterdis{\thechapter.}
\fi

\def\tableofcontents{\chapter*{\contentsname}\@starttoc{toc}}
\def\listoffigures{\chapter*{\listfigurename}\@starttoc{lof}}
\def\listoftables{\chapter*{\listtablename}\@starttoc{lot}}

\def\thebibliography#1{\chapter*{\refname}%
    \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{\refname}%
    % V1.6 add some rubber space here and provide a command trigger
    \footnotesize\vskip 0.3\baselineskip plus 0.1\baselineskip minus 0.1\baselineskip%
    \list{\@biblabel{\@arabic\c@enumiv}}%
    {\settowidth\labelwidth{\@biblabel{#1}}%
    \leftmargin\labelwidth
    \advance\leftmargin\labelsep\relax
    \itemsep \IEEEbibitemsep\relax
    \usecounter{enumiv}%
    \let\p@enumiv\@empty
    \renewcommand\theenumiv{\@arabic\c@enumiv}}%
    \let\@IEEElatexbibitem\bibitem%
    \def\bibitem{\@IEEEbibitemprefix\@IEEElatexbibitem}%
\def\newblock{\hskip .11em plus .33em minus .07em}%
% originally:
%   \sloppy\clubpenalty4000\widowpenalty4000%
% by adding the \interlinepenalty here, we make it more
% difficult, but not impossible, for LaTeX to break within a reference.
% IEEE almost never breaks a reference (but they do it more often with
% technotes). You may get an underfull vbox warning around the bibliography, 
% but the final result will be much more like what IEEE will publish. 
% MDS 11/2000
\ifCLASSOPTIONtechnote\sloppy\clubpenalty4000\widowpenalty4000\interlinepenalty100%
\else\sloppy\clubpenalty4000\widowpenalty4000\interlinepenalty500\fi%
    \sfcode`\.=1000\relax}
\let\endthebibliography=\endlist

\newcommand\chapter{\if@openright\cleardoublepage\else\clearpage\fi
                    \thispagestyle{plain}%
                    \global\@topnum\z@
                    \@afterindentfalse
                    \secdef\@chapter\@schapter}
\def\@chapter[#1]#2{\ifnum \c@secnumdepth >\m@ne
                       \if@mainmatter
                         \refstepcounter{chapter}%
                         \typeout{\@chapapp\space\thechapter.}%
                         \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}%
                                   {\protect\numberline{\thechapter}#1}%
                       \else
                         \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{#1}%
                       \fi
                    \else
                      \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{#1}%
                    \fi
                    \chaptermark{#1}%
                    \addtocontents{lof}{\protect\addvspace{10\p@}}%
                    \addtocontents{lot}{\protect\addvspace{10\p@}}%
                    \if@twocolumn
                      \@topnewpage[\@makechapterhead{#2}]%
                    \else
                      \@makechapterhead{#2}%
                      \@afterheading
                    \fi}
\def\@makechapterhead#1{%
  \vspace*{50\p@}%
  {\parindent \z@ \raggedright \normalfont
    \ifnum \c@secnumdepth >\m@ne
      \if@mainmatter
        \huge\bfseries \@chapapp\space \thechapter
        \par\nobreak
        \vskip 20\p@
      \fi
    \fi
    \interlinepenalty\@M
    \Huge \bfseries #1\par\nobreak
    \vskip 40\p@
  }}
\def\@schapter#1{\if@twocolumn
                   \@topnewpage[\@makeschapterhead{#1}]%
                 \else
                   \@makeschapterhead{#1}%
                   \@afterheading
                 \fi}
\def\@makeschapterhead#1{%
  \vspace*{50\p@}%
  {\parindent \z@ \raggedright
    \normalfont
    \interlinepenalty\@M
    \Huge \bfseries  #1\par\nobreak
    \vskip 40\p@
  }}

\newcommand*\l@chapter[2]{%
  \ifnum \c@tocdepth >\m@ne
    \addpenalty{-\@highpenalty}%
    \vskip 1.0em \@plus\p@
    \setlength\@tempdima{1.5em}%
    \begingroup
      \parindent \z@ \rightskip \@pnumwidth
      \parfillskip -\@pnumwidth
      \leavevmode \bfseries
      \advance\leftskip\@tempdima
      \hskip -\leftskip
      #1\nobreak\hfil \nobreak\hb@xt@\@pnumwidth{\hss #2}\par
      \penalty\@highpenalty
    \endgroup
  \fi}

\makeatother
```

I copied some code from `book.cls` and adapted some of che code of `IEEEtran.cls` to use `chapter`s rather than `section`s.

Appendices won't typeset in the right way.